# How to know if a process is using a Network Interface?

Tags: c#, .net, networking, network-interface

By .NET with C#, I know all the processes those are running on my OS. But how to know if they are using any of the Network Interfaces? 
I also have the list of Network Interfaces that my machine has, by C#.
Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this CodeSnippet:

[www.timvw.b](http://www.timvw.be/2007/09/09/build-your-own-netstatexe-with-c/)

Thats the Method you need:

```
ManagedIpHelper.GetExtendedTcpTable(true);
```

There you will get all PID, which you can parse to ProcessNames.

Comment: Thanks @Verni It has worked. Thank you very much.